# Resolving "error: expected identifier" in header file?

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, header-files

I do not understand what identifier is excepted in my dsoptlow.h.

I was practicing creating function declarations in headers. This should swap 2 values using only 2 variables and returning same variables, but with swapped values.

However during compilation this error message is shown and I have no idea what I got wrong or mistyped:

> error: expected identifier or '(' before 'int'

Also, if you can give a better version for my function to return multiple values it would be very much appreciated.

And last but not least, does a type defined in a function definition return that type in main function? So does it return a `struct` I defined as a new type, or integer?

[image: error message during compilation-time]

The following code is my header.

```
#ifndef _dswapoptlow_h
#define _dswapoptlow_h
struct dswap_opt_low(int inp_1; int inp_2;);
#endif
```

The following code is the function definition.

```
//dswapoptlow.c src file
#include "dswapoptlow.h"

struct _return{int a;int b;}; //Init a struct named _return for 2 integer variables. 

typedef struct _return _struct;

_struct dswap_opt_low(int inp1, int inp2)
{
    _struct _instance;

    _instance.a=inp1;
    _instance.b=inp2;

    _instance.a=_instance.a+_instance.b;
    _instance.b=_instance.a-_instance.b;
    _instance.a=_instance.a-_instance.b;

    return _instance;
}
```

Comment: Is `struct dswap_opt_low(int inp_1; int inp_2;);` supposed to be a function declaration, or a variable definition? It's neither.

Comment: Please learn how to create a [mcve] to show us, one that replicates the exact error you show. While it's easy to figure out in this case, mismatching error and code could lead us astray.

Comment: @WeatherVane Is `dsawp_opt_low(int inp_1, int inp_2);` legal?

Comment: If you add a *proper* return-type then that would be a valid forward declaration of a function.

Comment: This `struct dswap_opt_low(int inp_1; int inp_2;);` and this `_struct dswap_opt_low(int inp_1, int inp_2;);` is not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dswap_opt_low` in the header is a function declaration. The function returns a `struct _return` and takes two parameters.

The correct syntax is

```
struct _return dswap_opt_low(int inp_1, int inp_2);
```

Also, you can move the definition and typedef of `_struct` into the header so that this is visible there. Then you can use

```
struct _return{int a;int b;}; //Init a struct named _return for 2 integer variables.
typedef struct _return _struct;
_struct dswap_opt_low(int inp_1, int inp_2);
```

Note that it is a bad design practice to use `_` in the first character of an identifier. I would suggest that you change the name and use more descriptive types.

Additional Note - Your function `dswap_opt_low` returns a local variable `_instance`. If the returned value is used elsewhere in the program it will result in undefined behaviour and you will get unpredictable results.

Answer (score 1):

The message is quite confusing (there should be another error), but your function is returning a `struct` and the compiler doesn't know the size of this `struct`

Move these two lines:

```
struct _return{int a;int b;}; //Init a struct named _return for 2 integer variables. 

typedef struct _return _struct;
```

from `.c` to `.h`

Comment: I did, however now it returns 2 error messages. One for `dswapoptlow.h:4.27`, that there is no expected identifier or`(` before `int`. The second one is for `dswaptoplow.h:6:1`, that there is no expected-qualifier-list before `typedef`.